# URL Encoding while getting Referrer from request

Tags: url, encoding, referrer

I am using request.getHeader("Referer") to get the current page, on certain cases the obtained url seems to be encoded.

i.e., instead of http://, the url gets encoded to https&#x3a. How do i prevent this encoding?

Comment: Decode the url. Can you provide some info as to which backend technology you're using (e.g. node.js, java, etc).

Comment: Ya decoding works...My question is only on certain rare cases or times i am able to reproduce this. Any specific reason on why referrer gets encoded.